# coding basics if / else and return (for example in javascript)

Tags: if-statement, return

I have been some time coding, not to much as you will see (1-2 years), but I am facing this question and I am feeling ashamed.
This is not the first time I am confused about it. I have looked in some books of other languages as Java, but I can't solve it by myself.

**Why in this script the return is undefined?**

```
const factorial = n => {
  let result = 1;
  const rec = (n) => {
    if(n>0) {
    result = result * n;
    rec(n-1);
    } else {
    console.log(result)
    return result;
    }
  }
  return rec(n);
};

console.log(factorial(5))
120
undefined
```

PS: I edited to clear what I would like to understand. Why function rec is not returning **result**?

Comment: If you remove the `console.log` from within `factorial`, what does it do? What effect does the line `factorial(n-1);` have?

Comment: main thing I would like to understand: why return is not working in "else". Whatever I write and return, it returns undifined.

Comment: The answer is that `factorial(n-1);` *does nothing* without the `console.log`. In the call `factorial(5)`, there is no return, control falls off the bottom of the function

Comment: I made some edition. I am returning in the else, why function rec is not returning this value?

Comment: Because the call to `rec(5)` doesn't visit the else. Only the call to `rec(0)` does

Comment: It does visit the else. See the log => 120. This come from else.

Comment: At the point where you have a `return` there are 5 copies of `rec`, each with their own value of `n`, in-progress. Only the newest of them will return a number, the rest fall off the end.

Comment: "It does visit the else." No, that's the `rec(0)` call, not the `rec(5)` call

Comment: what's the sens of else and return then? I want to say to my function: "if you reach 0, please return final value result to the function". Is has non sense else in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has multiple calls. Either return from all of them, or none of them.

```
const factorial = n => {
  if(n>0) {
    return factorial(n-1) * n;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
};


const factorial = n => {
  let result = 1;
  const rec = (n) => {
    if(n>0) {
      result = result * n;
      rec(n-1);
    }
  }
  rec(n);
  return result;
};
```

The alternative is to loop, not recurse

```
const factorial = n => {
  let result = 1;
  for (; n>0; n--) {
    result = result * n;
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: I am really glad and appreciate your time. I am still a little bit confused why else return is undefined and not result value if it is in the end of the function, but I understand better how to make recursion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @titoih the function happens multiple times, each is independent of the others. returning from the innermost function doesn't mean the outermost function returns.